# MySql is not starting after setting sort_buffer_size

Tags: mysql

As I updated **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** as below -

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
sort_buffer_size = 512K
```

to apply the changes, I wanted to restart but it is not stating.

> - mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
> - Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> - Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-09-22 14:46:47 +06; 2min 2s ago
> - Process: 4116 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
> - mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
> - mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
> - Stopped MySQL Community Server.
> - mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
> - mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
> - Failed to start MySQL Community Server.

Any idea, how to start mysql ?

Comment: What does this have to do with error 1064? You can't get a SQL syntax error if the server isn't even running.

Comment: are you inside `[mysqld]` subpart ?

Comment: Look for `[mysqld]` in `my.cnf` and add `sort_buffer_size = 512K` below that line

Comment: Don't see [mysqld] in my.cnf

Comment: Then you need to add a line `[mysqld]` and write `sort_buffer_size = 512K` below that line

Comment: Thanks @MadhurBhaiya it's working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**MySQL older versions (eg: 5.5)**: `sort_buffer_size` is a `[mysqld]` specific setting. So, you need to look for the line containing `[mysqld]` in your `my.cnf` file. Add your configuration entry below that line.

Alternately, if `[mysqld]` does not exist in your configuration file; you will need to create a new line entry stating `[mysqld]` and enter the sort buffer size entry below it. For eg (in your **my.cnf** file):

```
[mysqld]
sort_buffer_size = 512K
```

---

**MySQL version 5.7 on Ubuntu 16.04**: Configuration files have been separated into individual files. `mysqld` related configuration file (**mysqld.cnf** has been moved to **mysql.conf.d** folder. Full path will be like: `/etc/mysql/mysql.d.conf/mysqld.cnf`

You will need to edit the above mentioned file, and do the steps as discussed above.

**Additional:** A very good answer on [how to figure out optimal sort_buffer_size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/68443/160363)

Comment: do we need to restart db instance to see the changes for sort_buffer_size?

Comment: @AnweshValleshetti yes